# Использование генетического алгоритма для формирования команд

Tags: алгоритм, генетический-алгоритм

Задача состоит в том, чтобы подобрать команду под какую-то конкретную цель. Рационально ли на этапе подбора наиболее эффективной команды (необходимо учитывать, что члены команды должны хорошо ладить друг с другом, иметь необходимые профессиональные навыки) использовать генетический алгоритм, для генерации нескольких вариантов команд и выбора наиболее подходящей в соответствии с функцией приспособленности? Может быть, есть другие наиболее подходящие алгоритмы?

Comment: Тут слишком много сопутствующих вопросов. как долго мы можем подбирать/варьировать людей в команде? как мы будем сравнивать эффективность команд? какой уровень эффективности достаточно хорош, чтоб остановиться? как "обнулять" прошлый опыт людей при "генерации" новой команды? Это не говоря уже о том, что команда существует не в вакууме, а взаимодействует с другими людьми и командами внутри и вне. Плюс есть определённая динамика командообразования (хотя бы forming/storming/norming/performing), которую тоже надо бы учесть. В общем, попробовать интересно, но вряд ли что путное получится.

Comment: Если речь идёт о реальной команде а не о команде в компьютерном футболе, то думаю это вопрос HR, TeamLead, IT Director, вообщем человеческий подход. Никакой алгоритм никогда команду не подберёт... Например может быть личная неприязнь к определённым людям, и никакими тестами и формулами этого не определишь.

Comment: Может быть я слишком резко выразился, возможно какого-то результата и можно достичь, но это ОГРОМНАЯ работа, для большой команды людей в реализации такого проекта. Нужны составлять тестирования по очень многим аспектам, параметров может быть 1000и, и это всё надо будет в ручную учесть. Проверять работу алгоритма на реальных командах. Кто согласится это проверять на себе и сколько это будет стоить? И будет ли от этого профит в результате?

Comment: Была идея подключить нейросеть для распознавания наиболее эффективной команды. Но этот вопрос все равно трудоемкий, поскольку научить нейросеть в этом вопросе не так-то просто, а результат может не оправдать ожидания. Я не спорю о важности человеческого фактора и необходимости участия человека в качестве наблюдающего и направляющего. Поэтому в этой задаче и присутствует нечеткая логика и экспертные оценки.